# Matrix Algebra, Proof of some Trigonometric Identities

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Please Refer to the image to see the problem.  This was the easiest way to input the question as it has some difficult symbols to input from a keyboard.

[*Edit*: Image with task replaced by $\LaTeX$:]

> Consider the column vectors:
>
> $$x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} \text{ and } y=\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Treat these as vectors in a plane with x-coordinate being the first
>   element and the y-coordinate being the second element. Suppose x and y
>   make angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ with the x-axis.
>
> (a) Show that:
>
> $$x=\Vert x\Vert_2\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta_1)\\\sin(\theta_1)\end{bmatrix}\text{ and } y=\Vert y\Vert_2\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta_2)\\\sin(\theta_2)\end{bmatrix}.$$
>
> (b) Show that:
>
> $$x^Ty=\Vert x\Vert ~\Vert y\Vert\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$$
>
> (c) What is the value of $x^Ty$ when the two vectors are perpendicular
>   to each other?

Comment: Where are you stuck at?

Comment: I've worked my way through part a) already and I think I did it correctly.  Basically x1 = (x1^2+x2^2)^(1/2)*cos(theta1), x2 = (x1^2+x2^2)^(1/2)*sin(theta2)...but before I go on I wanted to be sure I was on the right track.

Comment: Just for your information: you can use $\LaTeX$ code here by using `$` or `$$` as a delimiter for mathematical expressions. This makes things much prettier. Posting your problem with the picture was fine I think, but I edited your initial post to demonstrate how Latex is used. Small hint for your (c) when you're there: when x is perpendicular to y, what's $\theta_1 - \theta_2$? Then use (b).

Comment: I'm sorry, stupid comment. Your other questions clearly show you know about Latex. My apologies. Well, at least I got +2, so it's not for absolutely nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) For a nonzero $x$, put
$$
x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}\\\frac{x_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}\end{bmatrix}=\|x\|_2\begin{bmatrix}c(x)\\s(x)\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Since $c(x)^2+s(x)^2=1$ and $0\leq|c(x)|\leq 1$ and $0\leq|s(x)|\leq 1$, we can set
$$
c(x) = \frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}=\cos\theta, \quad
s(x) = \frac{x_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}=\sin\theta
$$
for some $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$.

b) If 
$$
x=\|x\|_2\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta_1\\\sin\theta_1\end{bmatrix},
\quad
y=\|y\|_2\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta_2\\\sin\theta_2\end{bmatrix},
$$
then
$$\begin{split}
x^Ty&=\|x\|_2\|y\|_2\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta_1\\\sin\theta_1\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta_2\\\sin\theta_2\end{bmatrix}
=\|x\|_2\|y\|_2(\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2+\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2)\\
&=\|x\|_2\|y\|_2\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)
\end{split}$$
using a [handy trigonometric identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities).

c) $x$ and $y$ are perpendicular if $\theta_1-\theta_2=(2k+1)\pi/2$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ for which $\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)=\cos((2k+1)\pi/2)=0$. Hence $x^Ty=0$.

Comment: Wow! Looks great!  That link you put to the trig identities was very helpful as well.